# analyzing worse case in a linear time selection

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, induction

I have a question I'm trying to figure out.  I don't have any good sources or examples so I found an example to go off of provided by [Bowdoin College](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/spring14/Lectures/7-selection/selection.pdf).  Below is my attempt to solve this problem based on that source.

Specifically what I was looking for is:

1. Did I do everything right (i.e. is my answer correct)?
2. Is my step 5 math correct (each of the two `num elements` & my `Induction`)?
3. I finally found a constant `c = 201` and `n = 538` that satisfies my inequality of:

   `101c + n <= (24/101)cn`

But i just kept plugging in numbers for `c` and `n` until I found a pair that worked.   Is there a more efficient and easier way to do this, then trial by error?

---

**Question and answer**

[image]

Comment: Step 2 is wrong.  Insertion sort is $O(n^2).$

Comment: @saulspatz I have seen many examples where it is O(n) but they all have 5 elements.  Is that the threshold?  Is there a way to prove that elements >= 6 in insertion sort is O(n2) ? I checked out Khan Academy, but they have an example of 5 with O(n2)  (in reverse order) so I'm confused.  Source of Khan is https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/insertion-sort/a/analysis-of-insertion-sort.  Source of example where 5 elements is O(n) http://home.cse.ust.hk/faculty/golin/COMP271Sp03/Notes/MyL04.pdf

Comment: Also @saulspatz does the rest of the answer seem right?